# Xcode - if file is clicked, find existing tab instead of always opening new

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 10.0, say I have two files open in two tabs, fileA.txt and fileB.txt. I have the tab with fileA active and focused. If I try to open fileB.txt **from the navigator**, I want it to switch to my existing tab that already has fileB open rather than opening fileB in the focused tab (and knocking out fileA).
I believe this is the default behavior of Eclipse and Visual Studio.

Bonus question: how can I make a **single-click** on a file in the navigator **do nothing**? Currently it opens the file (a behavior I only want when I double-click).